# Responsive table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive

I want to make a responsive table that will show 2 sections a time, the labels and the values.

The labels would be fixed and the data would be a slider.

So far I have this:

```css
[class^=col] {
  float: left;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.frame {
  overflow: scroll;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.sub-row {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}
.sub-row:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="sub-row"></div>
    <div class="sub-row">Test1</div>
    <div class="sub-row">Test2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="sub-row">Col1</div>
      <div class="sub-row">bla</div>
      <div class="sub-row">bla</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="sub-row">Col2</div>
      <div class="sub-row">bla</div>
      <div class="sub-row">bla</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But notice that the data is being displayed one below each other. I want it to be displayed side by side, hidden in the panel so I can slide it. How can I do this?

Comment: Any reason you are making a table with divs instead of <table>? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see a working example:

This is acheived using flexbox

```
thead, th{
  display:flex;
}
```

http://codepen.io/dbushell/pen/wGaamR

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make a resposive table refering to that code!

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Glad to have helped you!